# What are normal closure of a complement of a subgroup and intersection of all normal subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What are normal closure of a complement of a subgroup and intersection of all normal subgroups?

If X is a nonempty subset of a group G, define the normal closure X complement of X to be the intersection of all normal subgroups of G that contain X; that is, core H = {g in G | g in aHa^-1 for all a in G} = intersections of {aHa^-1 | a in G}

Sorry first time posting here and I'm not good with codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then the subgroup generated by its complement, $\langle G-H \rangle=G$ (this follows from the fact that a group cannot be the union of two proper subgroups). Hence the normal closure, $(G-H)^G=\langle G-H \rangle^G=G$.